# Estimating Dataframe memory usage from file sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, operating-system

If I have a list of files in a directory is it possible to estimate a memory use number that would be taken up by reading or concatenating the files using `pd.read_csv(file)` or `pd.concat([df1, df2])`?

I would like to break these files up into concatenation 'batches' where each batch will not exceed a certain memory usage so I do not run into local memory errors.

Using `os.path.getsize()` will allow me to obtain the file sizes  and `df.memory_usage()` will tell me how much memory the dataframe will use once it's already read in but is there a way to estimate this with just the files themselves?

Comment: Not really. It depends on whether you are specifying the data types beforehand. If you don't know anything about the file itself and leave pandas to its own devices when parsing the data, I don't think there's anything you can do

Comment: If you knew what the data types should be for each column (mine will have one object column followed by floats for the rest) could you force types on them to get that number?

Answer (score 0):

You could open each CSV, read first 1000 lines only into DataFrame, and then check memory usage. Then scale estimated memory usage by number of lines in the file.

Note that `memory_usage()` isn't accurate with default arguments, because it won't count strings' memory usage. You need `memory_usage(deep=True)`, although that might overestimate memory usage in some cases. But better to overestimate than underestimate.